# Adjective that means "Control Freak"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for an adjective for a person that can be described as a control freak or having OCD. However, I was look for a word that is less harsh than control freak.

The girl was _____; while playing tea time with her friends, she dictated everyone's roles, where they were to sit, and what they could say.

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea why there are two answers. [I've asked on meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10746/bug-editing-my-own-answer-duplicates-it), so hopefully it'll be sorted before I delete it.

Comment: Edit, it's gone now. please get >10k rep to see it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Controlling

> [exercising] restraint or direction over; dominate; command

Source: [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/controlling)

It also sounds like they are:

#### Manipulative

> influencing or attempting to influence the behavior or emotions of others for one’s own purposes

Source: [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/manipulative)

Answer (score 3):

***bossy***

The girl was *bossy*

Merriam Webster says:

> inclined to domineer.

Answer (score 0):

from https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fastidious

**fastidious**

adjective

1: Very attentive to and concerned about accuracy and detail.

‘she dressed with fastidious care’